Git error with Python virtual environment. Can not execute git add
I am relatively new to python virtual environments and I recently set one up while starting a new backend project to learn django, for which I also initialized a git repo. I seemingly set up everything correctly, however, when I reopen the project I noticed that I could no longer commit changes to my git repo. I get the following error when I try git add . :
fatal: unable to access 'C:\Users?peri/.config/git/config': Invalid argument

A few things I have noticed that are odd:

When I open the project the address shown in the terminal does not point to where my project is. The terminal should be pointing to 'C:/Users/vperi/Documents/Python Dev/WebDev/online_marketplace where the project is found but instead the following address is shown in the terminal C:/Users/vperi/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code.
It also appears that a virtual environment is already running when I open the project in vs code (not the one I set up).
When I cd into the correct folder and start the virtual environment for the project the terminal shows that 2 virtual environments are active (see screenshot).

I've tried deactivating the virtual environment mentioned in point 2, changing directories to my project directory, and then trying git add . but still get the same 'fatal' error.
I assume this has to do with git bash and my virtual environment but am new to python virtual environments so I'm pretty lost at the moment.

Somewhere, in some Python config file, you have stored your path name without protecting the backslashes.  \v (as in "C:\Users\vperi") is one of the special escape characters.

Git generally doesn't like spaces in paths and you have Python Dev which could be causing the issue. See also: https://superuser.com/questions/870663/how-can-i-use-git-add-command-on-a-file-whose-path-includes-a-directory-with-s

View .venv/Scripts/activate and find export VIRTUAL_ENV=. Check its value. In some version of Python like 3.11.2, there is a bug here. It's expected to call export VIRTUAL_ENV=$(cygpath "D:\path\to\venv\python") to transform D:\path\to\venv to /d/path/to/venv on MSYS. It would cause an error if it's export VIRTUAL_ENV="D:\path\to\venv\python".


Delete .gitconfig file in C:\Users\vperi\.gitconfig
Navigate to C:/Users/vperi/Documents/Python Dev/WebDev/online_marketplace and delete any .venv folders

I suspect that there are 2 .venv folders so check carefully
Delete the .venv folders

Right click on vscode (I am assuming you pinned it to taskbar and click New Window

Navigate to your project folder

After the window fully loads, open a new terminal, make sure its in the correct path. and run:


virtualenv venv

MAKE SURE YOU ARE USING POWERSHELL
And run
.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1

If this shows an error, then run this:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Invoke-Expression ".\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1"


Press ctrl+comma to open up the settings and search for
python.terminal.activateEnvironment
And set it to false

Using git bash is not recommended unless you have a specific need to use bash-like interfaces.
Explanation:

Clearly, your git config is messed up, so I suggested you delete it
I highly suspect you have 2 .venv folders, so I suggested you delete them and start from scratch
By setting python.terminal.activateEnvironment to false you are disabling the autoload feature of vscode that loads virtual environments
I suggest you stick to powershell for now because its much easier dealing with powershell if you are developing on windows


Are you sure their git config is messed up? Based on the path (with a ? in the place of a /), it's possible that an environment variable got corrupted (perhaps by VS Code when launching the terminal). I don't think recreating their gitconfig is worthwhile unless there is evidence to show that it is the culprit. At this point, there isn't enough evidence to suggest that.

True, but I assumed that the '?' was just a copy-paste error

@Advik your solution seems to have worked. Thank you for the quick reply. Whats weird is that I did not have 2 .venv folders. It was just the one. None the less, deleting the .gitconfig file and recreating the virtual environment with the steps you provided seems to have resolved the issue. Thank you for you help!

It seems like the terminal is broken. A first step could be to turn auto-activation off in the VSCode settings:
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false

Then reload the Window.
This should fix your Problem with the two venvs.
Issue known from: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22037
